# POST following request using python

Tags: python, http-post

I am new to python

How can i use python to post the following, i need to login to CISCO VNMC and do login and grab cookie from the output, and do logout

```
 POST https://10.193.34.70/xmlIM/mgmt-controller

 Please enter content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to be POSTed:

 <aaaLogin 

    inName="admin" 

    inPassword="cisco@123"/>
```

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/unified_computing/vnmc/sw/1.3/VNMC_API_Reference_Guide/VNMC_XML_API_2chap2.html#wp1162932

Suggest me some way for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

You can do your 1st request, get the cookie from the response, and whatever you need to do with this module.

Answer (score 1):

Use the state of the art **requests** module for Python

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/